# Autocomplete text field pods and IQKeyboardManager

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm writing an application and want to implement autocompleting textfields. I am populating an array with the data that I want to compare the entered text against. I've tried a couple of Pods online but these aren't working.

My Application already utilises the IQKeyboardManager Pod, does anyone know of any autocomplete pods which a compatible with this or will I need to write the code for it myself?

Comment: What does it mean by autocompleted textfield?

Comment: So when you start typing in a textfield it gives suggestions which match what you have entered so far and a set array of Strings. i.e. if you type 'Ash' it will suggest 'Ashok Londhe' if it is contained within the array

Comment: Okay. Please update the question with example so that everyone can understand it easily.